# Why we need use streams in Java?

Tags: java, android

Suppose, I need get file. Why I need use streams?

```
File file = new File(directory, "image_name.jpg"); 

FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn);

streamIn.close();
```

Why it's to complicated? When I need copy of array I just call `clone()` and all bytes of array `a` copy to variable `b`.

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4...1000};
int[] b = a.clone();
```

Why we can't get copy of file in similar simple way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = someMethodToGetCopyOfFileFromDisk(pathToFile);
```

?

Comment: That's exactly what a `FileInputStream` is.

Comment: It's not complicated. Your version is more complicated as it's totally unclear from where your method comes from

Comment: Because that's the API provided by Java. Besides, something in your code has to interpret the byte stream to construct a `Bitmap`. Why load the entire file into memory, just to convert/parse it into something else, like a `Bitmap`? Better to process the bytes as they are read from the byte stream.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying understand streams, and you comment was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line in your code takes care of a concern, there is almost no "incidental complexity". Keep in mind that the fact that `Bitmap` takes an `InputStream` to construct itself is called *flexibility* and widely appreciated for it. If the API was "simple" and just asked for a filename, it would force you to provide the data in a file on the disk. If it took a `byte[]`, it would force you to preload all the data to the heap, so the heap would have to hold both the `byte[]` and the `Bitmap` at once, giving rise to possibly significant memory overheads.

As for having to close the stream, since Java 7 this has become much simpler. Here's how I would write a method that transforms a `File` into a `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap load(File f) {
  try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I correctyl understand, `inputStream` is raw array of bytes. And when we call `decodeStream()` it parse this bytes in some concrete Java object? It's similar to deserealizing JSON to object? Yes?

Comment: `InputStream` is about raw bytes, but it is not an _array_ because its API allows only sequential access. Otherwise, yes, input streams are usually parsed (deserialized) into some higher-level objects.

Comment: What mean "close stream" term? It means, that we can't append bytes to it anymore? Like make variable `final`?

Comment: You don't append bytes to an `InputStream`, you _consume_ the bytes from it. But yes, you cannot obtain any bytes from a closed stream. The importance of closing a stream lies in releasing the native system resources associated with it, a file descriptor in the case of a `FileInputStream`.